# Extract substring from a certain indexposition of (huge) string

Tags: php, string, strpos

Let say I have a huge string where I want to extract e certain value belonging to a name, for example the stockprice of Apple.

Let say say the string look like this (in reality its html but that does not matter here)

$output = "nsdfsdnfsnfdnsdfnueruherdfndsdndnjsdnasdnn **Apple** dndfjnfjdf647tgtgtgeq";

*I want to extract the value 647.*

The real string is maybe some hundred thousand characters.

I can reveal the position of Apple by:

```
$str = "Apple";
$pos = strpos($output, $str);
```

let say the function returns 87310 which is the indexposition of the first letter in Apple.

Here comes my question? Is there an easy way to extract the value when I know the startposition of Apple? I have looked for such a function but can right now not find it.
I could solve this easily by just looping ahead of the name Apple and then extract the relevant characters? But it would at the least save keystrokes to use a function for this instead.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just pull out the stock price, you would want to do something like this:

Search your string for "Apple" and save $position + 5 (length of Apple). Search directly after $position, one character at a time, for the first character that is_numeric and add that to a string, $stock_val. Continue adding all subsequent characters until you find one that !is_numeric. Here is my clunky code:

```
$position = strpos(strtolower($str), "apple") + strlen("apple");
$temp_str = substr($str, $position);

$stock_val = "";

do {
$char = substr($temp_str, 0, 1);   //Take first char of $temp_str
$temp_str = substr($temp_str, 1);  //Remove that char from $temp_str

    $is_acceptable = (is_numeric($char) || $char == "." || $char == ",");
if($is_acceptable) {            //If the char is_numeric, add it to $stock_val
    $stock_val .= $char;
}
if(!$is_acceptable && $stock_val != "") {
    break;                     //If the char is NOT numeric AND $stock_val
}                              //already has characters, break.
} while(strlen($temp_str) > 0);        //Repeat while there are still characters
```

Comment: This will return '647' using the string you specified above. If this isn't exactly what you meant/what you were looking for, or if the code needs clarification, please let me know!

Comment: ok thanks a lot - i'll take a look into this. :-) But theres a little problem i did not mention it in the question - the stock prices is not only traded in dollars - also cents , that is 647.1, or with "," 647,1.

Comment: I was wondering about that! I will edit it momentarily to accept both '.' and ','.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. Maybe not lowlevel ;-) as with if-else-structures but this feels like real php. THANKS!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you know the start position so calculate the end position by doing strlen($str) then use substr to cut away the unwanted string
something like this using substr

```
$portion = substr(substr($string, 0, -(strlen($string) - $end)), $start);
```

Comment: so this brings up the question, if you already know the word then what is the point of pulling the word out of the document?

Comment: I have no idea but that wasn't the question :)

Comment: @Xeoncross - not pulling out the word (that is Apple) - pulling out the stockmarketprice of Apple

Comment: @user2365568 in that case you're probably better regexing it if you're searching by ticket you'll want not just the ticket but ticket + a few characters afterwards for the value which will probably be a $ or £ or eurosymbol + a varying amount of ints then a full stop . then an int as pricing will be in the format of `$111.11` so you can quite easily regex that for first pattern occurance after the occurance of your input ticket code / string